# Convert input String to List after each character without spaces in python

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to ask for an input of an alphanumeric phone number and convert it to a list so that I can convert the alphabet letters to numbers.

I have this for the input:

```
number=str(input("Enter Alphanumeric phone number:"))
number.split("")
```

and to try and convert it I tried

`number.split("")`

which gave me an error, and

`list(number)`

which just left it as a string.

Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use list comprehension for one line input. 
In this method you will not need to write more number of lines.

```
list = [int(i) for i in input()]
```

for input`123456789` you will get `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues you have with both approaches is you still have to convert the string to a number in this case `int`.

```
numbers = str(input('Enter Alphanumeric phone number'))
numbers = list(numbers)
numbers = [int(number) for number in numbers]
```

for input of `1234567899` you'll get `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9]`

Comment: It sounds like the input string might contain letters.

Answer (score 0):

`list(number)` will convert the string to a list of characters. It sounds like you need to assign the result back to `number` though, like this:

```
number = list(number)
```